Are Higgs mechanism and SSB different phenomena?
In the Standard Model, the Higgs mechanism is associated with the Spontaneous Symmetry Breaking (SSB).
My understanding is that it is the Higgs field which breaks the $SU(2) \times U(1)$ symmetry at a sufficiently large coupling constant (or high temperature).
However, I am aware of some constructions like the Abelian Higgs model, which was rigorously constructed in $2D$ as in this paper (Project Euclid).
So, my questions are as follows

Firstly, are the Higgs mechanism and SSB conceptually different phenomena? That is, can we have one phenomenon without the other?


I am aware that SSB is an example of phase transition. Is the Higgs mechanism "itself" also a phase transition?

Thank you for any clarification.

The answer is yes to both your questions.
You can have SSB without the Higgs mechanism, but you cannot have the Highs mechanism without SSB. In fact, the Higgs mechanism is the SSB of a (local) gauge symmetry*: you can have SSB of global symmetries, so no Higgs mechanism, but to have the SSB of a gauge symmetry you clearly need Higgs mechanism.
Since the Higgs mechanism is an example of SSB, also the Higgs mechanism is understood as a phase transition: is a phase transition for gauge systems.
In fact, for the electroweak theory you have two phases: the (unbroken) Higgs phase, and the (broken) Coulomb phase.
The same happens in supercondutors, where the transition to superconductivity is in fact made through the Higgs mechanism, which gives mass to photons due to electron condensation. So again you have a phase transition from the non-superconductive phase to the superconductive one.

*There are some mathematical technicalities which states that gauge symmetries cant be spontaneously broken, but you can obtain the same effects using some gauge invariant operators. Check Elitzur's theorem for that.

Thank you for your answer. I haven't heard of "broken Coloumb phase". Could you provide any reference?

‘the transition to superconductivity is in fact made through the Higgs mechanism, which gives mass to photons due to electron condensation’ Do you have a reference for this?

@Keith the coulomb phase is the colloquial name of the broken phase of the electroweak group, called Coulomb due to the fact that the gauge group that's left is the one responsible for the Coulomb (i.e. EM) interaction

@my2cts you can find it in chapter 21.6 of Weinberg's QFT vol. 2.

@LolloBoldo I see. The Proca equation cannot be renormalised because of gauge invariance, so the Higgs mechanism is used.
